# pthread, pthread on windows, pthread trouble , linker errors, pthread linker error on msvc 2008/2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, pthreads, linker-errors, pthreads-win32

I am running a pthread on MSVC 2010 and I have include pthreadVC2 .lib & .dll .
from below site http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/
http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/pthread.html
but i am getting these error 
can any one educate me on this

```
Fun_os.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pthread_key_create referenced in function _FUN_InThreads
Fun_os.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pthread_create referenced in function __FUN_ThreadCr
Fun_os.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pthread_attr_init referenced in function __FUN_ThreadCr
Fun_os.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pthread_setspecific referenced in function __FUN_sThreadEtry
Fun_os.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pthread_join referenced in function __FUN_ThreadJoin
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991618/adding-extra-pthread-dll-in-visual-studio-2010?noredirect=1#comment33332168_21991618).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install pthread\_win32 (Windows pthread / posix thread library) for Visual Studio 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654073/how-do-i-install-pthread-win32-windows-pthread-posix-thread-library-for-visu)

Answer (score 0):

For me [this](http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/pthread.html) is working fine. so may be you need recheck your project property and ensure the setting you did in (release/debug) mode and in same mode you are building the project.